# JSON Parser Nodejs giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting the following string when I try to `JSON.parse` the string, I get the following error

```
undefined:1
{"device":"FaclonTest","data":[{"tag":"LATITUDE","value":1903.5091},{"tag":"LONGITUDE","value":07251.0348}]}
```

Where am I going wrong, can someone help?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Good Lord, please allow Dark Lord to use debugger and online json parse tools

Comment: `var news2 = news.replace(" ","").replace("\n",""); console.log(news2);
 var jso= JSON.parse(news2);` When parsing I get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with `"value":07251.0348`. Number should not begin with 0. If you remove that leading zero, everything should start working. So try to change `"value":07251.0348` to `"value":7251.0348`